# Como efetuar uma busca desconsiderando caracteres especiais FireBird na Clausula WHERE

Tags: sql, firebird, view, acentuação, where

Estou fazendo uma View e na clausula `WHERE` ele não aceita um filtro deste 'Temporário' somente se retirar o acento Ex: 'Temporario'.

```
CREATE VIEW VWORDEMPRODUCAO (
CODEMPRESA
)
AS
SELECT
F002 AS CODEMPRESA
FROM MFT05O020
WHERE F020 <> 'Temporário'
```

Obrigado e fico no aguardo.

Comment: Dá algum erro? Se sim, qual?

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço bem o FireBird, por isso não sei se essa solução será viável, mas valide:

```
CREATE VIEW VWORDEMPRODUCAO (CODEMPRESA)
AS
    SELECT  F002 AS CODEMPRESA
    FROM    MFT05O020
    WHERE   (CAST(F020 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS) <> ('Temporário' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS)
```

A `Collation` **SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS** remove todos os caracteres acentuados, permitindo assim fazer a comparação sem eles.